# Backbone select not work

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using select function but returns empty value.I need to get only models with attribute tipo = value

```
var Integrated = Backbone.Collection.extend({
equalThan: function (value) {
var models = this.select(function (model) {
    return model.get(tipo) === value;
});

console.log(models);//empty
 },

})
```

tipo is attribute name, and value is attribute value

Comment: if `tipo` is the name of the property, it needs to be in quotes like `model.get("tipo") === value` and you need to use a comparison operator, to a setter.

Comment: What do you mean for comparison operator?

Comment: you have a single equal sign, which is an assignment operator. Take a look through here to learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Operators

Comment: I've fixed the equal sintax sign, but doesn't work

Comment: Ok now works..was only equal sign wrong